# Counting the letter 's' and 'S' from a file

Tags: c, function, loops, file-io

I am working on an assignment where I have to read a file in c and count the how many 's' or 'S' are in the txt file. I am almost done with the assignment, but I am having trouble with counting the letter 's' in the function `int CountLetterS(char Str[1000])`. Now the assignment requires a function that counts the the number of 's'. I did the assignment without the function and the code runs as it should. There is a block comment in the code. Running with the block comment and the without the function gives me the output that I want. but I can't figure out how to do it with the function. It outputs to `Count: 4`. But it should output to `Count: 950`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int CountLetterS(char Str[1000]){
    int countLetter = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(Str); i++) {
       if (Str[i] == 's' || Str[i] == 'S'){
                countLetter++;
            }
        }
    return countLetter;
}


int main() {

    FILE* fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("slow_glass.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("File did not open");
        exit(1);
    }

    char str[1000];
    int count = 0;

    while (fgets(str, 1000, fp) != NULL){
        count = CountLetterS(str);
    }


/*
    while (fgets(str, 1000, fp) != NULL){
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] == 's' || str[i] == 'S'){
                 count = count + 1;
             }
         }
    }

*/

    printf("Count: %d\n", count);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it is because you are re-initializing countLetter = 0 everytime the function is accessed. Thus it is returning the number of s/S in only the last line I believe

Comment: The `strlen(Str)` call is superfluous. `for (i = 0; Str[i]; i++) ` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are calling the CountLetterS() function, count variable gets new value.
So, the count you are printing is only of last part of your text file.

Instead use:

```
int count = 0;
count += CountLetterS();
```

Or another Method.

No need of gets instead use fgetc.

```
int CheckForS(char    ch)
{
  if(ch == 'S' || ch == 's')
  {
      return 1;
  }
  else
  {
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Inside main()

```
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{
    count += CheckForS(c);
}
```